# Reference instance method outside class definition

Tags: python, function, methods, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass a method as an argument outside of the definition of a class. However, since it's not defined in that scope, it doesn't work. Here's what I'd like to do:

```
def applyMethod(obj, method):
    obj.method()

class MyClass():
    def myMethod(self):
        print 1

a = MyClass()    

#works as expected
a.myMethod()

#"NameError: name 'myMethod' is not defined"
applyMethod(a, myMethod)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

myMethod is only defined in the namespace of MyClass. Your code could look like this:

```
def applyMethod(obj, method):
    method(obj)

class MyClass():
    def myMethod(self):
        print 1

a = MyClass()    

a.myMethod()

applyMethod(a, MyClass.myMethod)
```

Now you're referencing `myMethod` from the namespace it exists in, and calling the equivalent of `obj.myMethod()` from the `applyMethod` function.

That's all you need - the `instance.method()` is just syntactic sugar for `ClassName.method(instance)`, so I just rewrote the `applyMethod` function to work without the syntactic sugar, i.e. be passed in as the raw `MyClass.myMethod`, then gave it an instance of `MyClass` as its first argument. This is what the `a.myMethod()` syntax is doing in the backend.